# Error: Device token should be a hex string on Device Token Validator

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

What I am ultimately trying to do is update a `LiveActivity` using a push notification, and so to me the very first step is being able to send a push notification from the [Push Notification Console](https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard) to my device.

I am currently using a simulator device, and my app is organized as follows:

- Main target has bundle id `com.nick.main`
- Widget target has bundle id `com.nick.main.widget`

This is how I am attempting to get my token:

```
do {
        let Activity = try Activity<Attributes>.request(
            attributes: Attributes2,
            contentState: initialContentState,
            pushType: .token)

        Task {
            for await pushToken in deliveryActivity.pushTokenUpdates {
                let pushTokenString = pushToken.reduce("") { $0 + String(format: "%02x", $1) }

                print("pushTokenString: \(pushTokenString)")
                
            }
        }
    } catch (let error) {
        print("Error requesting Live Activity \(error.localizedDescription)")
        
    }
```

[image]

When it runs it does print out a token from `print("pushTokenString: \(pushTokenString)")`, and this is what I am attempting to use on the push notification console. I have tried the Device Token Validator on the push notification console and when I put the token to check it I always get the error: `Error: Device token should be a hex string`. I also tried to use the send feature of the push notification console selecting the different bundle ID's and each produces this error when it is attempted:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "bad-request",
  "reason": "Invalid push token",
  "requestUuid": "53f450a0-1160-4be3-aa37-bbd65ba79e58"
}
```

I would also add that I also tried this:

```
let pushTokenString = pushToken.reduce("") { $0 + String(format: "%02.2hhx", $1) }
```

And it produces the same token as

```
let pushTokenString = pushToken.reduce("") { $0 + String(format: "%02x", $1) }
```

Here are 2 examples of the tokens that are produced:
`80340949ad01bdb0db1bb77332cd7dd9721a8dc9758960d59c112d3af61af6b96b8c6cfe1bedc3cdb8cd240f57b65a6565dc7e17e0e03ee2730bd8745a874912dc284d4d4081e73a8c7a1d5feada388b495734a47f397cea198983fa1629f3db9468bb0e04c351c600c6ccbffba2a7b8e79023b0b0379641cedfe73619b1fc5b`

`806169d3b506558327fabb72a85fe9f3d840cfa4980dae98dd51574ab1271b8ffa251bdb87175d1b16b1445aa6a8266ac86be4d4223aaaeaa5500f94452074843985a855cd53527f79299480ca2e9b9a3fecf68c7ce472a4c618cdfe148646c46c143f40985c26ad40a435df2808a61d9026d2c8a9def5e36f1b3e36bfe8a3b2`

These both have a length of 256, but I believe the length needs to be 64.

Any ideas/suggestions on what I am missing?

Comment: Did you make sure the token in the request body is the same as the one in `print("pushTokenString: \(pushTokenString)")`?

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted the token from the xcode console to the device token validatior / push notification console

Comment: Do you mind pasting the token you got from the console? Its length should be 64, like `"965b251c6cb1926de3cb366fdfb16ddde6b9186a8a3cac9e5f857679376eab7D"`.

Comment: May be off topic, but format `"%02.2hhx"` is suggested for the conversion, as explained in this blog post: https://nshipster.com/apns-device-tokens/#overturned-in-ios-13

Comment: The token printed out is: `80340949ad01bdb0db1bb77332cd7dd9721a8dc9758960d59c112d3af61af6b96b8c6cfe1bedc3cdb8cd240f57b65a6565dc7e17e0e03ee2730bd8745a874912dc284d4d4081e73a8c7a1d5feada388b495734a47f397cea198983fa1629f3db9468bb0e04c351c600c6ccbffba2a7b8e79023b0b0379641cedfe73619b1fc5b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue ended up being that I was generating the token on an iOS simulator. When I instead tried on a physical device it generated a valid token and worked as expected.